# Python in VS Code: IntelliSense not working properly for the object returned by the linspace function in numpy

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Python and trying to use VS code as my editor.

But when I use the
`linspace` function in `numpy`，the IntelliSense doesn't work properly for the returned object.

The doc of `numpy` and my example code's ouput all show that the returned object's type is **ndarray**, but the editor shows that its type is a **tuple**. So the IntelliSense cannot suggest the attributes and methods related to the **ndarray** type, which is a bit annoying.

my example code is as follows

```py
import numpy as np
    
a = np.linspace(0, 1, num=5)
print(type(a))
```

the output is:
[image: the code's output]

while the VS code shows:
[image: a VS code clip]

How should I fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In VSCode, the mouse hovering prompt here is provided by different language services, and it usually displays the basic data type,(`Number, String, List, Tuple, Set, Dictionary`) and the "type(a)" here is the class wrapped in numpy, and the returned "[numpy.ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html)" is the class, not the basic data type.